# クロージャに [weak self] をつけていない場合、予期しないメモリを参照することはありますか？

Tags: swift, ios, メモリ管理

## 前置き

`swift`でクロージャを書く場合に、`[weak self]`を付けていない場合、循環参照が起こりメモリリークしてしまう場合があります。
メモリリークしているのは、解放されていないオブジェクトなので、すぐに`self`がどのオブジェクトを参照しているのかソースコード上わかります。

## 質問

今回の質問は、`[weak self]`を付けていない場合に、付けていないにも関わらず、クロージャ内に記載した`self`は解放されており、コールバックなどで`self`が参照された時点では、使用していたメモリ空間が別のものとして使用され、アプリ自体が落ちる場合があるか？（もしくは不正なメモリをアクセスしてしまうというところまではいかず、単純にnil参照で落ちるだけでしょうか？）という質問となります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`[weak self]`を付けていない場合に、付けていないにも関わらず、クロージャ内に記載したselfは解放されており、コールバックなどでselfが参照された時点では、使用していたメモリ空間が別のものとして使用され、アプリ自体が落ちる場合があるか？***

ありません。

`[weak self]`を付けない場合、`self`はクロージャーに強参照で保持されています。クロージャー自身が生きている限り、`self`の参照先が解放されてしまい、他の用途に使われることはありません。

***もしくは不正なメモリをアクセスしてしまうというところまではいかず、単純にnil参照で落ちるだけでしょうか？***

上記したように、`[weak self]`を付けない場合、`self`の参照先がクロージャーの実行中に解放されることはないので、「nil参照で落ちる」こともあり得ません。

(ちなみに`[weak self]`を使用すれば、参照先が解放された場合には`self`は`nil`になりますから、不用意に「別のものとして使用され」ていることはないはずです。この場合変なことをすれば、nil落ちするのはもちろんです。`[unowned self]`だと「プログラマの自己責任」でそんなことは絶対に無いように気をつけて使わないといけません。自分自身で意味が完全に理解できていない限り`[unowned self]`は使わないほうがいいですね。)

---

クロージャーがらみで何か不審な挙動でも見つけられたのでしょうか?もう少し具体的な事例を挙げてもらえれば、何か付け足すことがあるかもしれません。

Comment: 「クロージャー自身が生きている限り」この部分がポイントな気がしてきました。`NotificationCenter`が不用意に使用されているようなコードで、不審な挙動があるように感じたのですが、そもそもクロージャ自体が解放されている可能性があるのかもしれません...が、具体例が上げづらく抽象的というか基本的な質問となってしまいました。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、 クロージャのコード自体は実行時に解放されることのないコード領域に配置されるので、逆に実行中なのにオブジェクトとしてのクロージャ(キャプチャしたオブジェクトの情報など持っている)が実行中に解放されてしまう、と言うことも起こり得ます。(本来はそれが起こるのはバグ。)`NotificationCenter`でクロージャを使うパターンで不審な挙動があるなんて話は割と最近にどこか(多分本家stackoverflow)で見たんですが、残念ながら具体的な記事は見つけられませんでした。何か見つけられましたら、情報共有していただけると助かります。

Comment: 承知しました。再現できる小さなコードを書こうとしているのですが、なかなかうまく（？）書けていない状況です(^_^;)

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、ありがとうございます。すでに十分ご承知だとは思いますが、Swiftコンパイラの最適化は時々やり過ぎることがあるので、最適化がかかる設定の方が「変なこと」は起こりやすいですね。こちら残念ながら一つ引っかかった記事は`self`の解放には関係なさそうでした。関係ありそうな記事を見つけたら、回答に追記するなどしておしらせします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とはいえ`NotificationCenter`がらみは、プログラマの意図しないデータ状況で通知が来て、メモリ解放とは全然関係ない文脈で落ちることも多いので、はっきりしたことが言えない状況です。何かあれば、追加 or 別途質問といたします。